# PHP foreach and explode array code not functioning properly

Tags: php, arrays, csv, explode

```
<?php
$string = file_get_contents("csv.csv");
$array = explode(",", $string);
$q = strtolower($_GET[q]);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    $result = explode(":", $value);
if (strpos($q, $result[0]) !== false) {
    $output = $result[1];
}
}

echo $output;
?>
```

Here is the content of the file `csv.csv` which I am turning into a string.

```
hello: how are you doing,
hi: what are you,
df:df
```

If `$_GET[q]` (and `$q`) is `hello`, the `$output` is `how are you doing`. However, if it is `hi`, I do not get the output `what are you` or if I do `df` I do not get `df`.

Any reason why this is occuring? Thank you in advance for your kind help.

Comment: `$_GET[q]` should be `$_GET['q']`.

Comment: Make sure to turn on error_reporting and display_errors, always in development. PHP will be complaining about an `undefined constant q` in `$_GET[q]`.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` _always when developing code_.

Comment: @Darren Good point from a purely syntaxical point of view, but really I've used `$_GET[q]` a tireless number of times, and it's no different from `$_GET['q']`. Also, I'm sure it has nothing to do with the problem that occurs...

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Error reporting *is* on.

Comment: @testo but it _is_ different. I causes PHP to use a behavior which is intended to save you from yourself, whereby it converts constants it doesn't know about into strings. It is a bad thing to rely on. If you have error reporting turned up to `E_ALL` (not suppressing notices) you will most certainly see notices that look like _Use of undefined constant q - assumed 'q'_

Comment: it is different. There is no constant q, you're making PHP work twice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exploding by commas, but the truth is you have each value separated by comma **plus line break**.

After exploding, your array is ["hello","\nhi...","\ndf:..."], that's why there's no match for the strpos comparison.

try

```
$array = explode(",\n", $string);
```

Edit: as @Michael Berkowski said, you could also trim the parameter

```
if (strpos($q, trim($result[0])) !== false)
```

The order of the parameters depends on what kind of partial match do you want to offer. With your current parameter order, the parameter "hi" would match "hi", "h" and "i" but not "high".

If you flip them as Michael suggest, the parameter "hi" would match "hi" and "high" but not "h" or "i".

Comment: To clarify what went wrong, the args to `strpos()` are `$haystack, $needle`, so you are searching `$q` whose value is `'hi'` for the literal string `'hi\n'` and that does not match. It would match if you flipped the args `strpos($result[0], $q)` instead, but trimming the linebreak either in `explode` or later with `trim()` is the solution.

Comment: Manually parsing a CSV is ugly and resulted in this exact problem, you should use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) as it will automatically take care of this issue

Comment: I use ```fgetcsv```, the only caveat is to check the setting ```auto_detect_line_endings```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually parsing a CSV use [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)

Using str_getcsv and replacing $_GET[q] with $_GET['q'] fixes the issue

```
    $csv = file_get_contents('csv.csv');
    $array = str_getcsv($csv);
    var_dump($array);
    $q = $_GET['q'];
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $result = explode(":", $value);
        if (strpos($q, $result[0]) !== false) {
            $output = $result[1];
        }
    }

    echo $output;
```